# Import XML-feed to Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a XML-feed that looks like this

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Name of store</title>
    <link>Link to store</link>
    <description>Google Merchant Center product feed</description>
      <item>
        <title>Producttitle</title>
        <link> </link>
        <description> </description>
        <g:id> </g:id>
        <g:condition> </g:condition>
        <g:price> </g:price>
        <g:availability> </g:availability>
        <g:image_link> </g:image_link>
        <g:gtin> </g:gtin>
        <g:brand> </g:brand>
        <g:product_type> </g:product_type>
      </item>
```

I need help getting this into Google Sheets in a proper way with a script. 
I now use this code

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B2').setValue('=importxml("URL2Feed";"//item//title")')
```

and it works for title, link abd description, but I'm not able to get g:* into the sheet. It gives me an #N/A

Can someone please help me out :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK. I got the import to work. To get the attributes imported, I use this code

```
IMPORTXML("https://URL2FEED";"//*[local-name()='id']")
```

I entered this code into A2, B2, C2 etc, but some fields doesn't have text. This is a productfeed from a store, and then the price get next to the wrong product.

So now I need a script that can parse this feed correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the attributes via the name without namespace.

And take a look at [this document](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160589?hl=en)